# How to test out the example angular-react-native-renderer project?

Tags: ios, angularjs, react-native

Has anyone successfully built and tested the sample project from [angular-react-native-renderer](https://github.com/angular/react-native-renderer) project? Regardless of how many times I try, the project launches Xcode and just hangs? Is this project really worth a try and can it be used to write iOS apps that have an Angular2 portal front-end that you do not want to change, and instead re-use? Is this scenario a valid use case for this project? If yes, how to test the sample project and use that to translate our existing Angular2 web pages? One of my colleagues who tried the same, had to restart his Mac.

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on OS X El Capitan and it launched in Xcode and ran the sample app inside the iPhone 6 emulator successfully. It can take a few minutes to load up for the first time. Also, I didn't have to restart the Mac.

I would suggest you follow the instructions on setting up your environment again from their [GitHub project page](https://github.com/mlaval/angular2-react-native-seed]).